# How do I use sftp:content to write an sftp message from memory

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to create an sftp file from memory using sftp:write and sftp:content. My dataweave code is:

```
<sftp:write doc:name="sftp from memory" doc:id="01bee2a1-69ad-4194-8ec8-c12852521e87" config-ref="SFTP_Config" path="#[vars.sftpFileName]" createParentDirectories="false">
    <sftp:content><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
        output application/csv
        ---
        payload.toplevel.secondlevel.bottomlevel[0],
        payload.more.andmore.andstillmore[0]
        ]]>
    </sftp:content>
</sftp:write>
```

It does create a file in the correct directory, but the contents are not the payload values. Instead, it is the actual dataweave code. The file contents are:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
payload.toplevel.secondlevel.bottomlevel[0]
payload.more.andmore.andstillmore[0]
```

I am using version 4.2.2 of the Mule Server and 1.3.2 of the SFTP component.

Comment: Could you please provide a payload example in JSON format? Thank you.

Comment: Mule version? SFTP Connector version?

Comment: I have added the mule version and sftp version to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually passing dataweave, you're passing a string. Press the `fx` button on fields when you're going to be using dataweave. The XML will look like this. Notice the extra `#[`? That indicates this is dataweave. Your dataweave is also invalid; you must output an object or an array of objects; to make your output an object, you wrap it in `{` .. `}` just like JSON, and use key-value pairs. When outputting this to CSV, the keys will be used as a header row unless you include `header=false` in the output line: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-csv#writer_properties

```
<sftp:write doc:name="sftp from memory" doc:id="01bee2a1-69ad-4194-8ec8-c12852521e87" config-ref="SFTP_Config" path="#[vars.sftpFileName]" createParentDirectories="false">
    <sftp:content><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
        output application/csv
        ---
        {
            someKeyName: payload.toplevel.secondlevel.bottomlevel[0],
            someOtherKeyName: payload.more.andmore.andstillmore[0]
        }]]]>
    </sftp:content>
</sftp:write>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: "literal mode" passes through the contents as a literal or string while "expression mode" executes the contents as a dataweave script.

Comment: It is complaining about the comma at the end of the first payload line:Invalid input ',', expected Function Call or ? (line 4, column 52):

Comment: @CountBoxer That is correct - expression mode means you are passing in a dataweave expression while literal mode means a literal string. Keep in mind when using a property place holder like ${some.property} you still use literal mode because this is, in essence, a templating system. The value gets replaced BEFORE the app runs. And yes, I didn't notice, but your dataweave itself was invalid. It must be a valid structure. I've updated my answer to reflect this; the key names will be used as a CSV header row. Check out https://dwlang.fun if you're new to dataweave

Comment: I don't remember the literal/expression modes being explained like that before, thank you! I tried to reach dwlang.fun, but it can't be reached. I will try again later. Thanks for the assistance and explanation!

Comment: @CountBoxer - ah, my bad. its http://dwlang.fun/ there isn't an HTTPS version for whatever reason. Click tutorial in the top right and it will bring you to an interactive dataweave tutorial.

Comment: This code work perfect! Any pointers on how to deal with an array in the payload that could generate multiple columns?

Comment: @CountBoxer - if I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking about handling a data structure that has nested elements? CSV doesn't support any kind of nested structure, so you'll need to map everything into a single layered object. If you need nested structures in your output and want to go with a flat file format, mulesoft support flat files. For more details on transforming the data, I would suggest posting another question with sample input and the desired sample output, with a specific question around the part you're having an issue with.

Comment: Additional question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726439/how-do-i-flatten-a-json-array-to-a-csv-file